# Update a specific cell when a value changes in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been tasked with creating a way for a column of data to update the most recent entry to cell at the bottom.  More specifically a loan portfolio amount is entered in for each month of this year and the most recent entry needs to also appear at the bottom of the column.  Here's what I initally came up with but this won't work for the last entry before the bottom.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

xC = 0

yC = 7

If (Target.Column = 3) Then

Do

prevInt = currentInt

currentInt = Sheet1.Cells(yC, 3).Value

If (currentInt = 0) Then

Sheet1.Cells(19, 3).Value = prevInt

xC = 1

End If

yC = yC + 1

    Loop Until xC = 1

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: can you just use a linked cell? or is the portfolio amount appended (not overwritten) every month?

Comment: It's a column of cells for each month (January down to December) and when the most current months amount is entered in its respecitve cell it also needs to display at the bottom.

Comment: I have a basic idea of what you are actually trying to do but before I post may I see a snapshot of your sheet so that I can get my references correct?

Answer (score 0):

i assume the cells below the most current month's total will always be blank, unless it's December. Otherwise i don't know how you'll know which is the most current:

```
Public Sub SetTotalCellValue()
Const portfolioColumn As Integer = 3
Const endRow As Integer = 14 'row of "total" cell

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim val As Object

rowCount = 2 'start at January, skip header row

'Set sheet = some sheet

'find last empty cell
For a = 1 To endRow
If sheet.Cells(a, portfolioColumn).Value = Empty Then
   sheet.Cells(endRow, portfolioColumn).Value = sheet.Cells(a - 1, portfolioColumn).Value
Exit For
ElseIf a = endRow - 1 Then
  sheet.Cells(endRow, portfolioColumn).Value = sheet.Cells(a, portfolioColumn).Value
Exit For
End If

Next a

End Sub
```